# React not updating state from redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to add redux to my react app.

My index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, compose, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import dashboardReducer from './store/reducer/dashboard';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  dashboard: dashboardReducer
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

const app = (
  <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
  </Provider>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    {app}
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Then, I have a store folder with actions folder and reducer folder.
In my actions folder, I have the actionsType.js:

```
export const TEST = 'TEST';
```

I also have the dashboard.js:

```
import * as actionTypes from './actionsTypes';

export const test = () => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.TEST
    }
};
```

And finally, the index.js to return the actions:

```
export {
    test
} from './dashboard';
```

Inside the reducer folder, I just have one reducer now, called dashboard.js

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actionsTypes';

const initialState = {
    counter: 0
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.TEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                counter: state.counter++
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default reducer;
```

I create, in my components folder, a test class Dashboard.js to test my redux.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import * as action from '../store/actions/index';

class Dashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            counter: 0
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <h2>Main Page: {this.props.ctr}</h2>
              <button onClick={this.props.onTest}>TEST</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        ctr: state.counter
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onTest: () => dispatch(action.test())
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard);
```

When I open the page, it just say "Main Page: ". Shouldn't it start with a 0 value? Also, When I click on the button "test", nothing changes.

Sorry, I'm just starting with react and redux, I'm probably missing a lot of configuration.

Thanks

Comment: FYI: `state.counter++` mutates the current state, this is an anti-pattern. Do `state.counter + 1` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not getting the value from the correct reducer. A nice way to debug that is logging the state inside the mapping:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log(state); // This will run with EVERY state change
    return {
        ctr: state.counter
    };
};
```

Since you named your reducer as `dashboard`, just call it there:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {

    return {
        ctr: state.dashboard.counter
    };
};
```

Comment: Thank you. It was simpler than I thought. Redux is very cool

Comment: You're welcome, bud :) Take a look into Context API too! I feel it is cleaner than redux and easier to get into

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**BEFORE**

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        ctr: state.counter
    };
};
```

**AFTER**

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        ctr: state.dashboard.counter
    };
};
```